# Trying to run babel : "cannot find module @babel/core"

Tags: babeljs

I'm trying to set up a build environment to explore react.
My build process uses gulp.

I installed packages like this:

> npm install --save-dev gulp-babel@7 babel-core babel-preset-env

After discovering that I needed to install something related to babel and react I also ran:

> npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

My .babelrc has this:

> {   "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"] }

My gulpfile has this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./src/js/main.js' ])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets : ['@babel/preset/react']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('test.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('test.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js')) ;
});
```

When I run 'gulp scripts' I get this:

```
[22:51:14] Using gulpfile ~/play/learning-react-2/gulpfile.js
[22:51:14] Starting 'scripts'...
[22:51:14] 'scripts' errored after 59 ms
[22:51:14] Error in plugin "gulp-babel"
Message:
    Cannot find module '@babel/core' (While processing preset: "/home/bob/play/learning-react-2/node_modules/@babel/preset-react/lib/index.js")
```

I deleted babel-core from node_modules, and reinstalled it using the command:

> npm install --save-dev @babel/core

If I look at the contents of node_modules, I see these packages related to babel:

> babel-code-frame/
>   babel-helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor/
>   babel-helper-call-delegate/
>   babel-helper-define-map/
>   babel-helper-explode-assignable-expression/
>   babel-helper-function-name/
>   babel-helper-get-function-arity/
>   babel-helper-hoist-variables/
>   babel-helper-optimise-call-expression/
>   babel-helper-regex/
>   babel-helper-remap-async-to-generator/
>   babel-helper-replace-supers/
>   babel-messages/
>   babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/
>   babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions/
>   babel-plugin-syntax-exponentiation-operator/
>   babel-plugin-syntax-trailing-function-commas/
>   babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol/
>   babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex/
>   babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator/
>   babel-plugin-transform-regenerator/
>   babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode/
>   babel-preset-env/
>   babel-runtime/
>   babel-template/
>   babel-traverse/
>   babel-types/

I'm guessing that at least one of them is "babel core"

So... how do I actually run babel from gulp? How do I run it at all?

Comment: please install `@babel/babel-core` and also `@babel/preset-env`. As far as I know, babel publishes the new packages under the prefix `@babel`

Comment: @JosefBiehler Is '@babel/babel-core' different from 'babel-core'? Is '@babel/preset-env' different from 'babel-preset-env'? I've installed the latter packages and attempts to install the former ones fail - they can't be found. If the packages you describe are different from the ones that I've installed, please let me know how to install them.

Comment: @JosefBiehler without further guidance I have no way of telling if I have installed the packages you have directed me to (in which case they simply aren't working) or whether I've installed packages with near-identical names.

Comment: of course the packages are different. Please have a look at e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-core . This package was updated 2 years ago. The same holds for `preset-env`. I have tested `npm install --save @babel/core @babel/preset-env` successfully. Accidentally I have written the wrong package name. It must be `@babel/core` instead of `@babel/babel-core`

Comment: @JosefBiehler ok - First I deleted 'node_modules'. Then I ran 'npm install --save @babel/core @babel/preset-env'. I also reinstalled the gulp module. I then run this: './node_modules/.bin/babel src/js --out-dir js'. This works as expected and desired. However, when I run 'gulp' I get "Error: cannot find module 'babel-core'. 

So the issue must be related to the gulp side things.

Comment: I found a (kind of) solution in this comment:  https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/124#issuecomment-476877592. After installing 'gulp-babel@next' the gulp task works. This isn't really a proper solution because I have no idea what this package is.

Comment: hey unfortunatelly I do not use gulp but webpack+react. Thus I can not help you anymore. sorry :-( maybe I find some time to test this with a small example in the next days

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by removing `node_modules` and I reinstalled packages (with `yarn` OR `npm install`). The problem was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `yarn add @babel/helper-environment-visitor` if you are using yarn, will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case [Victor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65721282/443836) doesn't help, [it may be worth a try to clean your machine's package cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73532346/443836) by running `npm cache clean`/`yarn cache clean` or removing the cache folder manually.