# Cannot find module @babel\types\lib\index.js after browserlist update

Tags: babeljs, create-react-app, yarnpkg, react-scripts

Seemingly out of nowhere, our React app (using [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)) cannot be built anymore. It fails to load a Babel module:

```
$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts build
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:371
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\dev\node_modules\@babel\types\lib\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:363:19)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:576:18)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:803:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-imports\lib\import-injector.js:10:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\dev\\node_modules\\@babel\\types\\package.json',
  requestPath: '@babel/types'
}
```

Indeed, after `yarn install`, there is no `lib` folder inside `node_modules\@babel\types\`.

The potentially relevant parts of the `package.json`:

```json
{
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "~7.15.3",
    "core-js": "~3.16.2",
    "platform": "~1.3.6",
    "prop-types": "~15.7.2",
    "react": "~17.0.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "~17.0.2",
    "regenerator-runtime": "~0.13.9"
     // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.5"
    // ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build"
    // ...
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My current environment is:

- Windows 10 Pro 19043.1889
- Node.js 18.8.0
- yarn 1.22.19

An update to `@babel/runtime@7.18.9` did not help.

I think the action that may have broken the build on my machine is `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`, which I was requested to run by a previous build. I do not see the connection though.

After the problem occured, I tried multiple things, so I am not sure in exactly which environment things still worked. It must have been:

- Node.js 16.x.x
- yarn >= 1.21.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was going on, but after cleaning the machine's yarn cache, the build works again. It can be cleaned by running `yarn cache clean` or by manually deleting the folder `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache`.

Curiously, when trying to reproduce the problem by running `npx browserslist@latest --update-db` again, I now experience this command [doing nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73532269/).