# Browserlist update does nothing

Tags: create-react-app, caniuse, browserlist

In our [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), the `node_modules\caniuse-lite\package.json` has version 1.0.30001251. `yarn build` tells me that

```
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```

But when I do this, the version in `node_modules\caniuse-lite\package.json` stays the same, and `yarn build` will request to run the browserlist update again. Our project's `package.json` and `yarn.lock` are unchanged. This is the output of `npx browserslist@latest --update-db`:

```bash
Latest version:     1.0.30001384
Installed version:  none
Removing old caniuse-lite from lock file
Installing new caniuse-lite version
$ yarn add -W caniuse-lite

# (Warnings about peer dependencies...)

Cleaning package.json dependencies from caniuse-lite
$ yarn remove -W caniuse-lite

# (Warnings about peer dependencies...)

caniuse-lite has been successfully updated

No target browser changes
```

Edit: Also posted at [GitHub](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/724).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up enforcing a recent caniuse-lite version by adding this to my `package.json`:

```json
"resolutions": {
  "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30001522",
},
```

The message about caniuse-lite being outdated has disappeared since then.